# How to drop keys from string json in java?

Tags: java, json

I have a json string like this:

```
{"a":"vala", "b":"valb", "c":"valc"}
```

I want to convert the above string to a JSONObject so that I can do something like:

```
testObject.remove("b");
testObject.remove("c");
```

So that I can easily print out the json string of:

```
{"a":"vala"}
```

What is the simplest way for me to do this?

Comment: What happened when you tried doing exactly that with `org.json.JSONObject`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is self answered.

Comment: what json library are you using?

Comment: For net.sf.json.JSONObject and org.json.JSONObject, you can try testObject.remove("b").remove("c").  However, it will cause a problem if the JSONObject don't have a key "b".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[org-json-java](https://code.google.com/p/org-json-java/downloads/list) can do the things you want

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JsonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JSONObject testObject = new JSONObject("{\"a\":\"vala\", \"b\":\"valb\", \"c\":\"valc\"}");
            testObject.remove("b");
            testObject.remove("c");
            System.out.println(testObject.toString());  // This prints out the json string
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The execution result is

```
{"a":"vala"}
```

Make sure you've downloaded and imported org.json-YYYYMMDD.jar from [here](https://code.google.com/p/org-json-java/downloads/list) before you run the above code.

Answer (score -2):

Firstly I think you need change title of question.

Secondly, If you want change from String to Json just using [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/) library

```
 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("{\"a\":\"valuea\",\"b\":\"valueb\"}");
```

---

Are you tried remove. http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#remove(java.lang.String)

Json.remove(key)