# Ignore one key while matching two Json responce

Tags: json, automation, rest-assured

I am comparing two JSON responses from two different end points and trying match them in automation with Rest Assured.

All is fine except one key "secondsToNextEvent" which have a different value in both Json due to time difference in Get request.

```
{
    "englishName": "Serie A",
    "boCount": 103,
    "termKey": "serie_a",
    "name": "Serie A",
    "eventCount": 17,
    "id": 1000095001,
    "secondsToNextEvent": 1649,
    "sport": "FOOTBALL"
},
```

so I would like to compare both Json but want to ignore "secondsToNextEvent". is there any method to do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack overflow is not a code writing service please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How are you trying to match them ? Are you converting the response as a string ?

Comment: @WilfredClement I am simply saving response and matching them as below.
assertThat(aResponce.jsonPath()).isEqualTo(bResponce.jsonPath());
should I convert response to String and take out what I dont need and match after that?

Comment: Just wondering if that could be done, I haven't tried that sort ! I will check and meanwhile you can give it a try

Comment: Incidentally, I just found this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34279941/how-to-drop-keys-from-string-json-in-java

This looks fine to me,You have to convert the response to a JsonObject and use the "remove" parameter to proceed further